# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined error when unit testing in angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

Why I am seeing this error when making my unit test on a function that need to be called : here is my code, first the code of .spec.ts :

```
it(' doit appeller le serveur quand le boutton ok est cliqué, pour envoyer l option du choix du code', () => {
  let spy = spyOn(authService, 'choixReceptionCode').and.callFake(t => {
  // on est pas besoin de se qui retourner du serveur l essentiel la fonction a ete appelle 
  return Observable.empty();
});

component.choix('mail');
  // comme ça on a testé si la fonction 'connexion' a été appelle ou nn
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

And here is the function in the component.ts:

```
choix(choice:string)
{
  console.log("ggggggggg"+choice);
  this.router.navigate(['saisirCode']);
  this.choiceReceptionCode.choix=choice;
  this.choiceReceptionCode.user=this.serviceAuthentification.getUserId();
  this.serviceAuthentification.choixReceptionCode(this.choiceReceptionCode).subscribe(
  (data)=>{
      console.log("the response in choixReceptionCode");
      console.log(data);     


  },
  (error)=>{
      console.log("Error in choixReceptionCode ");
      console.log(error);
  });
}
```

when executing ng test i found this error,
[the picture that showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWnad.png)

I know the problem is in this line:

```
this.router.navigate(['saisirCode']);
```

in the component.ts file because when i comment it the test pass, so how can I solve it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can try to provide a mock for router.

something like:

```
let router = jasmine.createSpyObj("Router", ["navigate"]);
```

and then:

```
router.navigate.and.callFake(()=>Observable.of(your stubbed data to return here));
```

Then create an instance of your component by injecting the router mock

```
let component = new MyComponent(router);
```

At this point you can call `this.router.navigate` when inside the method `choix` because `this.router` will refer to the injected service that you have already mocked and provided.

Comment: thanks a lot; I found a solution i changed the place of this instruction :this.router.navigate(['saisirCode']); to the service function because any way i need to router the user so when calling the server i router him and make my http.post simply, and the function of the server is callFake.